# Meaning of "rows between 15 preceding and 15 following"

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

```
WITH trips_by_day AS
                      (
                      SELECT DATE(trip_start_timestamp) AS trip_date,
                          COUNT(*) as num_trips
                      FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips`
                      WHERE trip_start_timestamp >= '2016-01-01' AND trip_start_timestamp < '2018-01-01'
                      GROUP BY trip_date
                      ORDER BY trip_date
                      )
                      SELECT trip_date,
                          avg(num_trips)
                          OVER (
                               order by trip_date
                               rows between 15 preceding and 15 following
                               ) AS avg_num_trips
                      FROM trips_by_day
```

Could anyone explain to me the meaning of `rows between 15 preceding and 15 following`?

Comment: It's called "moving average", over 30 days in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that `avg(num_trips)` is calculated not over all rows but over 31 rows (max) - 15 adjacent rows with `trip_date` lower than in current row, current row and 15 adjacent rows with `trip_date` greater than in current row. Of course when there are fewer than 15 rows from any side then fewer rows are taken into the calculation.

An example:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (value INT);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT value,
>        AVG(value) OVER (ORDER BY value ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING) avg2
> FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> value |   avg2
> ----: | -----:
>     1 | 2.0000
>     2 | 2.5000
>     3 | 3.0000
>     4 | 4.0000
>     5 | 4.5000
>     6 | 5.0000
> ```

Let's take row 3. The *frame* defines that we should take rows from 2 preceding till 2 following. The "2 preceding" rows for row 3 is row 1, "2 following" is row 5. So `AVG` is calculated for all 5 rows between 1 and 5 inclusive, and average is 3.

Let's take row 2. The "2 preceding" rows for row 1 is the only row 1, "2 following" is row 4. So `AVG` is calculated for 4 rows from 1 to 4, and average is 2.5.

One more example:

> ```
> SELECT value,
>        AVG(value) OVER (ORDER BY value ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) avg2
> FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> value |   avg2
> ----: | -----:
>     1 |   null
>     2 | 1.0000
>     3 | 1.5000
>     4 | 2.5000
>     5 | 3.5000
>     6 | 4.5000
> ```

Let's take row 3. The frame defines that we should take rows from 2 preceding till 1 preceding. The "2 preceding" row is row 1, "1 preceding" is row 2. So `AVG` is calculated for 2 rows from 1 to 2, and average is 1.5.

Let's take row 1. The is no both "2 preceding" and "1 preceding" row. So no rows for `AVG` calculation, and the output is NULL.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eac1f05b4df491f2620c196062c2ab37

Answer (score 3):

> `rows between 15 preceding and 15 following`

This clause specifies/limits the rows over which the average for that row is calculated.

In your query `avg_num_trips` is a running average of the number of trips (on a day), calculated, not over all the rows, but only over maximum 31 rows, namely the 15 rows preceding the date of the trip, the row itself (current row) and the 15 rows that follow the date of the trip.

See the documentation: [SELECT - OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql)